# Angular-JS File Upload using angular-file-upload - Limiting File Size display message

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload. i have added a filter to limit the file upload size. But i cannot find how to catch it so i could display a message to the user.

```
self.uploader.filters.push({
   'name': 'enforceMaxFileSize',
   'fn': function(item) {
        return item.size <= 10485760; // 10 MiB to bytes
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
self.uploader.filters.push({
   'name': 'enforceMaxFileSize',
   'fn': function(item) {
       if(item.size >  10485760){
          alert('Max file size is 10485760');
       }
       return item.size <= 10485760; // 10 MiB to bytes
   }
});
```